# Move a punching bag backwards and forwards from a fixed point

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation

I am creating a boxing app. I had to move a punching bag in back and forwards directions ..Not able to do it. Any suggestions?

```
self.punchingBag.layer.anchorPoint =CGPointMake(0.5,.5);

CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
if(!check)
{
    check = true;

    t = CATransform3DRotate(t,60.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 1,0,1);

    self.punchingBag.layer.transform = t;


}
```

Comment: This is not enough information. What do you mean with "not able to do it"? This is simply an image? How do you want it to behave (describe it _in as much detail as possible_)? How does it behave right now? Do you have trouble setting up the animation? Etc. pp. **Edit your question (do not comment!)** and add as much detail as possible.

Comment: neet to move the punching bag on z axis in backward and forward direction..Its not moving on z axis..

Comment: One problem is that you need to translate the anchor point of the punching bag to the origin before doing the rotation, and then translate it back to its original position.

Comment: yeah i have to move the bag backward and forward from a fixed point..so i think rotation is not the solution ..

Comment: @BharatLal: *sigh*... Why don't people _ever_ provide the information they were asked to provide? Why don't people _ever_ edit their question when they're asked to? I guess what you're trying to do is rotate around the _x_ axis instead, but I'm not sure _since you didn't provide enough information_.

Comment: I was using hit and try method to get the proper flow ...but not able to move it in a backward direction and forward direction.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess what you want is an animation where it appears as if the punching bag would swing towards you and then back from you. This means to rotate around the x-axis at the top of the view, while also applying a perspective transformation. Here's a way to do it:

```
UIView *bag = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 50, 100)];
bag.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.window addSubview:bag];

bag.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0); // Where we want to rotate around.
CATransform3D perspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0/-800; // Perspective transformation. Experiment with it.

// The animation.
CABasicAnimation *swing = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
swing.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(perspectiveTransform, -M_PI_4, 1, 0, 0)];
swing.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(perspectiveTransform, M_PI_4, 1, 0, 0)];
swing.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
swing.duration = 1;
swing.autoreverses = YES;
swing.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[bag.layer addAnimation:swing forKey:@"swing"];
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code ..but its get shrink and getting back to original position but not moving backward and forward..

Comment: Experiment with the `perspectiveTransform.m34` if the effect isn't pronounced enough for you.

Comment: Hey dark awesome code on experimenting with .m34 almost got it but there are some issues like that background image causing half the punching bag making it disappear .also anchor point is not getting fixed in orgin..